# Running the Gradle task 'assembleDebug' on a Flutter project results in an error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, gradlew

I'm having issues with running a flutter project.
Here's the error displayed on the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A3003 in debug mode...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I tried all I've seen so far on stack overflow no avail. I also changed the directory to `distributionUrl=gradle-5.6.2.zip`

Comment: Please post your full `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and the output of `flutter doctor -v`.

Comment: Flutter Doctor says no issues found.      
  #Thu Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

Comment: That is not a proper distributionUrl.